# Get the name of current app style sheet in PyQt

Tags: qt, styles, pyqt

How can I get the name of current style sheet of my PyQt app?

```
app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
print app.styleSheet()
```

`app.styleSheet()` returns nothing.

```
app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
print app.style()
```

return `<PyQt4.QtGui.QCommonStyle object at 0x0000000019BB4678>`

I need a string, for example 'plastique'

Comment: What do you mean by a "name of style"?

Comment: i mean "plastique", "windows", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the class name of the current style, if that's what you're looking for.

```
print app.style().metaObject().className()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is exactly what i am looking for. Gives me this result "QadskDarkStyle", "QWindowsStyle" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not use stylesheets for rendering of GUI. When you set up a stylesheet Qt generates corresponding QProxyStyle and use it. It is not possible to reverse this operation. When stylesheet is not set - then Qt may use native OS API for rendering controls.

Comment: According the comment below, seems i can get the name of the class with current application style.

Comment: Yes. Not I understand, what about your question is. Usage of stylesheets cunfused me